# how to fetch facebook event from event id in code ingnator?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I have the following query for fetching of events from facebook:

```
$fb_events = $this->facebook->api('/me/events?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,id,description,cover,picture,venue&limit=1');
```

but I want fetching from event id I tried:

```
$fb_events = $this->facebook->api('/$event_id/?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,id,description,cover,picture,venue&limit=1');
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fb_events = $this->facebook->api('/' . $event_id . '/?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,id,description,cover,picture,venue');
```

Of course you need to authorize a user who is invited if you want to get details of a non-public event. Here´s how you do this with the PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: this is working fine thank you but not for non public event. i am getting error. how to avaoid this?

Comment: for that, you would need to authorize a user who is invited. i will add a link to my answer.